# Image tag is not rendering with 'react-native-web'

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am new to react. I have a use case where I have to cache the image which is at the third party server.(want to avoid too many server calls to render an image every second) For this, I am using **react-native-web**

My application is a react web application. The code snippet is:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native-web';

class ImageComponent extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => { this.timer(); }, 2000);
    this.setState({ interval });
    const urlOfImages = ['https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png'];

    const preFetchTasks = [];

    urlOfImages.forEach((url) => {
        preFetchTasks.push(Image.prefetch(url));
    });
}

  render() {

     const images = ['https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png'];
     const text = 'something';
     return (
       <div>
                <span>{ text }</span>
                <Image source={{ uri: images[0] }} alt="Banner" title="Banner" border="0" />
               <Image source={{ uri: images[0] }} alt="Banner" title="Banner" border="0" />
                <Image source={{ uri: images[0] }} alt="Banner" title="Banner" border="0" />
                <Image source={{ uri: images[0] }} alt="Banner" title="Banner" border="0" />
       </div>
      );
  }


}
```

Through the network tab, I could see that there is just **one request being made to download the image from the server**. This is expected by the Image tag but, none of the Image is being rendered on the browser.

Can anyone please direct to the problem that the Image tag isn't being rendered or is there a better way to cache the image from the server using react?

Comment: try like this: `<Image source={{ images[0] }} alt="Banner" title="Banner" border="0" />`

Comment: If you `console.log(images[0])` in the render() method, after you've declared it, what do you see?

Comment: The same url - https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png

Comment: @Jigar, thanks for the suggestion but it gives a compilation error. Parsing error, unexpected token. Expected a ,

Comment: ya, I had pasted line, but I meant to say use any other var directly . remove uri

Comment: Even that didn't work. :(

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj  Did you get it work? Post your suggestion if you have done it.

Comment: @Balasubramanian No, it didn't work. I used a workaround to achieve this. I make a network call to server to get all the required images, I save them in a map with the key image path(URL) and value as the image tag. I refer to this map to get the image tag if the key is present else I create a new tag.